# Dr.Racket issue between versions

Tags: scheme, racket

I am using Dr.Racket version 6.12. I am getting the following error for equality operator.

```
> (= 2)
. . =: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: at least 2
  given: 1
  arguments...:
```

However, I was told that in version 7.8, we will get

```
> (= 2)
#t
>
```

Both `mit-scheme`, and `clisp` are evaluating to `T`. The book `Common-lisp: A gentle Introduction`, is claiming to get the error as described above.

I am a bit confused, whether I am wrong, or is it an implementation issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Racket 6.12, `(= 2)` *is* an error. In the [6.12 documentation](https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.12/doc/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._%7E3d%29%29), you can see that at least two number arguments are required for `=`.

But, later versions of the documentation, [starting with Racket 7.1](https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/7.1/doc/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._%7E3d%29%29) include a note:

> *Changed in version 7.0.0.13 of package base: Allow one argument, in
> addition to allowing two or more.*

Comment: In Racket 6.12, `(= 2)` is _not_ a syntax error. `=` is a procedure, not a form. Calling it with wrong number of arguments doesn't cause a compile-time error, only a runtime error.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase With optimization settings a runtime error might become a compile time error. Here `=` is the primitive from `racket/base` and `2` is a constant so the whole thing can be evaluated compile time to just `2`. Eg. try running `(define (test) (undefined-variable 10))` and hit run. It will fail because racket knows before it gets run that the binding will never exist.

Comment: @Sylwester: An optimization in Racket should not change runtime error into a compile-time error. If it does, I would consider that a bug.

Comment: @Sylwester: I'm not sure why you brought up the undefined variable issue. Are you suggesting that the program _could have_ successfully compiled, but it is not due to optimizations? If that's the case, the answer is no. The unbound id error occurs during macro expansion, and not due to optimization.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase It isn't a compile error in any other scheme systems. I tried changing the language to R5RS and R6RS but DrRacket has the same issue. An unbound (not yet defined) global, even in a closure that is never called is a compile time error. If I do the same lines one by one in the interactive wondows it behaves more like a typical scheme.  The issue is that a top level program is converted to a racket module and it seems to expect all identifiers to be allocated by the end of the parsing of that file. Wouldn't a guaranteed runtime error be a pretty good compile time error?